# Regex to match two words with a space in between

Tags: regex

Working on a NER problem, i have a very huge txt file with words and tags.After spending hours on cleaning it, i want to finally sort it out.
What i have is

```
MCWG 
23-11-2011 O
DOP 
01-06-1989 B-NUM
BG O
Name O
```

but as we see the first word does not have a tag,same for the third word.
Can anyone suggest a regex which matches a word which does not have a space and a second word after it.That way i remove them ,and get something like this.

```
23-11-2011 O
01-06-1989 B-NUM
BG O
Name O
```

I have tried `\b[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+\b` and `\w+\s\w+` but they dont seem to words

Any suggestions would be really helpful.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use: `^\S+ +\S+$` as regex

Comment: @anubhava OP seems to want to match the opposite of what you matched so that they can remove the matched string.

Comment: ok if OP wants a regex for removal then use `^\S+$`

Comment: @anubhava That does not seem to match anything. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57676062/2191572)

Comment: There are no spaces on left or right of `DOP` as in your example and then `^\S+$` will match single word lines otherwise use: `^\s*\S+\s*$` to allow for leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: @anubhava There is certainly a space to the right of `DOP` if you copy+paste the sample from the post; likewise with `MCWG`. The leading space detection is just insurance against data that OP doesn't know they have.

Answer (score 0):

You tried `\w+\s\w+` but you have to include the hyphen together with the word character using a character class as that is not matched by `\w`.

Note that `\s` also matches a newline.

Instead of remove, you could match them:

```
[\w+-]+ [\w+-]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QFUDxv/1)

To match a word without spaces to remove them:

```
^[\w-]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mRm7pe/1)

If leading and trailing spaces also should be considered, you could match optional leading and trailing tabs and spaces. Note that if you want to match 1+ non whitespace chars instead of word chars you could use `\S+`

```
^[ \t]*\w+[ \t]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
^ *[^ ]* *$
```

It searches for anything not a space surrounded by optional spaces.

https://regex101.com/r/JHzeC2/2